# What are the submodule and checkout commands of git for?

Tags: git

I hope my question is not out off topic.

I am trying to install [OpenBR](http://openbiometrics.org/) on my laptop (Ubuntu 14.04). Following the [instructions](https://github.com/biometrics/openbr), I found these 3 command lines:

```
git checkout <tag>
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

I wonder if someone could explain me what is their meaning ?

Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by myself :)

[git submodule (update and init)](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)

> Submodules allow foreign repositories to be embedded within a
>   dedicated subdirectory of the source tree, always pointed at a
>   particular commit.
>
> They are not to be confused with remotes, which are meant mainly for
>   branches of the same project; submodules are meant for different
>   projects you would like to make part of your source tree, while the
>   history of the two projects still stays completely independent and you
>   cannot modify the contents of the submodule from within the main
>   project

[git checkout](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

> Updates files in the working tree to match the version in the index or
>   the specified tree. If no paths are given, git checkout will also
>   update HEAD to set the specified branch as the current branch.

Comment: When in doubt, start with `man <first two words of git command>`: `man git checkout` and `man git submodule`.